# Accurev: Cannot remove workspace/stream

Tags: accurev

I'm trying to remove a workspace (or clone it to look like the parent, but I can't seem to do either). When I try, however, I get this message: `Cannot remove workspace test_workspace, because it has a non-empty default group.`

From what I've read, it means that there are active files (as shown by the 3 little green dots to the right of stream). I've tried everything to get those to go away but they just seem to stick around and therefore result in me being unable to remove the stream.

Alternatively, I could completely wipe out the stream and replace with the parent version, but I can't seem to do that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to purge the active files in this workspace.

Open the workspace and click on the "Default Group" filter -> select the files -> right click -> revert to backed.

If no files appear in the "Default Group" filter, click on the stranded filter and do the same as above to revert those files.

If you are using AccuRev 6.x, click on the outgoing mode and click on "Member" and "Stranded" to get a list of the active files.

Once you have done that, you can remove the workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm on Accurev 6.0.1. I open the workspace, click the outgoing tab, and then enable member, overlap, and stranded. I see a list of files, most are (defunct) or (member) with one (stranded). If I right click a file and say `Revert to basis` (no revert to backed option) I get this error: `Unable to purge changes in given stream. 
Can only use dynamic non-root streams or 
the current workspace.`

No idea what else to try, but if you have any, I'm all ears.

Comment: Is this your workspace or someone else?  Is the workspace registered to this machine or a remote machine?  If this is your workspace, do the following....Click on View -> Workspaces -> Select Workspace -> right click -> Edit -> Click on Finish.  Once this is done make sure the workspace directory exists, if it does not, create it....once this is done, perform the steps above.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here, fixed it following @jstanley's comment.

Open Workspace-> select it-> right click-> Edit.

In that prompt, I set the Location path to where I wanted it to put it on my local machine.  For some reason, it was unable to "create a folder" and threw errors, so make sure `Append Workspace name` is unchecked and you select a folder that already exists.

It then populated the folder on my local machine attached to the workspace.  And `revert to basis` worked, so afterwards I could remove the workspace and delete the folder.